# How to connect to my database with javascript and change a users username

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Right now I have a site that I only allow about five people to log into.

Those five people every time they login have to read an NDA and type their name in two text boxes provided. First and last name. When the user presses the submit button they are either taken to the site, if their name is correct, or logged out of the site if they type in anything other than their name.

Right now I am using javascript to do this since I don't know how to use php to do this.

If the user does not enter his name in correctly the first time I want the user to be logged out, like what I have now, and I also want this users username to be altered by adding, "xxx10017969" to the end of his username. This will prevent him from logging back in and require him to contact me so I can fix his username in the database.

here is the HTML:

```
      <form method="post" action="index.php" style="width: 600px;"><p>By typing your first and last name below you are bound by this contract. If you type anything other than your first and last name, you will be logged out and your account will be deleted.</p>
<p><input type="text" value="First Name" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" value="Last Name" name="family_name" id="last_name" />
<input type="date" value="Date" name="signiature" /></p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Access Site" onclick="checkforname();" /><p>
      </form>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function checkforname() {
  var fname = "<?php echo "$identity->first_name"; ?>";
  var lname = "<?php echo "$identity->family_name"; ?>";

  var enteredFname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  var enteredLname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

  if (enteredFname == fname && enteredLname == lname) {

  }
  else {
    window.location = ("login.php?logout");
  }

  }

  </script>
```

Comment: you should always do such a validation on server side using PHP. Doing the user verification on the client side is not good as, users can by pass it.

Comment: Your solution is not secure at all. 
Are you aware that user first name and last name is written in plain text and could be read if one check the source code of the page?

Comment: Does the javascript run on the client's browser?  If so, there is absolutely nothing preventing someone from looking at the code and bypassing this logic.

Comment: @M.Hryszczyk It is the users first and last name they are entering. Why would they need to look at the source code to see their own name? haha

Comment: You create vars fname and lname which contain values passed from php script. I suppose you retrieved it i.e. from DB and it contain the values that should be entered by the user?

Comment: @M.Hryszczyk yes. that's it. its their first and last name. if they look at the code I could careless, they still have to enter their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in PHP instead of javascript -

The form submits to index.php, so that is where the logic should be.

If you want to leverage the way you redirect to login.php?logout, than index.php would have to have code something like this in it:

```
<?php

// Code to populate $identity from the database goes here

// Checks if user entered fields match database record
if ($identity->first_name != $_POST['first_name'] ||
    $identity->family_name != $_POST['family_name'])
{
    // Code to disable account goes here, but need to see a sample of
    // your existing php database code to show how to modify first_name
    header("Location: login.php?logout");
}
```

Keep in mind any headers should be processed before the php prints anything including newlines ... so if index.php is an "in-line php" html page, make sure this happens at the very top of the file before the html portion starts. The opening `<?php` tag should be on line 1.

Also, this assumes you have a way to lookup the user again from a session or something to get the $identity variable populated with the user record.

There are some other things that ideally would be done here like sanitizing the user input in the post fields, and checking if post fields are empty to not generate warnings, but those are lessons for another time.

EDIT: Please show your existing php code when it is interacting with the database, like how it populates $identity, otherwise a specific solution cannot be provided.

Comment: All this does is check if the user is the person logged in, essentially doing nothing for me. The page is already protected by this. Please read above what I am asking for. If the user does not sign his name correctly while logged in the users username is changed and he is then logged out. the name is changed so he cannot login in again.

Comment: Modifying the first_name in the database requires more details about if your code uses a library or framework of some sort to connect to the database, or just raw php. Also consider a new database column like "disabled" instead of changing the first_name, you would set "disabled" = 1. Seeing a sample of database code from elsewhere in the app would help - like the population of $identity perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect to a server side database directly with javascript, since it's a client side language. Getting server side information into javascript is typically accomplished using an AJAX call, telling javascript to post some information to the server and get back a response, which can then be processed.

Answer (score 1):

You should never validate a user using JavaScript. It should always be done on server side using PHP. Doing the user verification on the client side is not good as, users can by pass it. If you use the code you have above, the username and password will be in the source code of the page and anyone can see them by viewing the source of your page.

I would recommend doing this. When the user enters the first and last name, submit to form to  login.php page. Verify the user on that page using PHP and if the user is valid allow him through, else redirect to the login.php?logout page.

Comment: I don't know PHP and don't know how to do this. Javascript is fine for me for now.