# Change a number from database through php

Tags: javascript, php, database, checkbox, echo

I am trying to communicate with database MySQL and change a number from a certain cell-box. I have created some check boxes, and i want each time i check one of those to change the specific number in database.

I don't mind helping me in other, but i am not so good that's why.
I believe i want something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627019/how-to-connect-to-my-database-with-javascript-and-change-a-users-username) but i haven't understand quite well his post.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you have to give them something to work with.  Paste in what you are trying and any errors that you are getting so folks can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I can't understand how to say to my database to change something in particular with code, not just connect that's where i am stuck

Comment: This is WAY too broad. We're not going to whip up an entire js/ajax + php + sql system for you.

Comment: I am not asking that, sorry for the misunderstanding, simply a 2 line code on how to refer to a specific row and line to my database

Comment: please include the two lines you have so far in your question and we can take a look.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about what your problem is. You don't know how to write the query? You don't know how to retrieve values from the form? How to plug values into the query? You think you know how but you're getting error messages that you don't understand? If you don't know how to do any of this, then I think this is really the wrong place to be asking. You need to get a book or find a web site on "how to write php/mysql programs". I don't mean to be rude, but a forum like this is not a good place to get a complete class in how to write programs.

Comment: Yeah you are right, and i think expressing your beliefs about something or someone despite being good or bad, if they are bound to help him you should do so, what i am saying is thank you for your time   writing that post and i was definitely not asking the right thing in that question. Anyway Quixrick helped me and i figured what i wanted out so sorry for the spam :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you just connect to the database.  Write a query to do the work and then execute that query.

In this example, you have a variable named `$checkbox_count` which has the number you want to update the table with.  If it's not a number, put single quotes around it.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('DATABASE HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

$query = "UPDATE table SET Checkbox_Count = $checkbox_count WHERE Id = 1";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('MySQL Error');
```